# Hide an element if div is empty for an html generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

Below is the html snippet:

```
<div class="row activityrow">
   @using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadFile", "GetData", FormMethod.Post, new {        target = "_blank" })){
      <label id='label_@data.test.Replace(".",@function_name).Replace("          ","")'><input type="checkbox" class="selectall" /> Select all</label>
      <div class="containsdata" style="column-count:2;width:100%;">
        @{ var count = 0;}
        @foreach (var item in data.Documents)
        {
           @if (@item.testdata.Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "_").Replace("&","_").Replace("?", "") == function_value.Name)
           {
             <div class="right8">
               <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="chk_@item.ID" value="@item.ID" name="chkId" />
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link" id="@item.ID"          value="@item.ID" name="Id"> @item.Title.Replace("Deploy ","")</button>
                </label>
            </div>
            count++;
        }
    }
 </div>
  @if (count > 0)
  {
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="selectedDownload" name="submit"> Download Selected</button>
  }
  else
  {
     <script>hideSelect('label_@data.test.Replace(".",          
       @function_name).Replace(" ", "")');
     </script>
 }
```

in the above I want to display the label for select all ONLY if the count > 0. I tried calling the hideSelect function to do that but it doesn't work. Below is the JS

```
<script>
  function hideSelect(args) {
  args.hide();
  console.log(args);
}
```

1. It says hide is not a function of args. I tried args.style.display = 'none' as well but that didn't work either.
2. The div shown above shows up if a button is clicked. The args printed do not match what for the one I clicked (nothing prints for it). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is `args`?  Can you confirm that it translates into the ID of the targeted element correctly? Can you provide an example of the fully rendered HTML?

Comment: args is supposed to be label_@data.test.Replace(".", @function_name).Replace(" ", ""). I checked the html generated after and it looked correct. It looks like: hideSelect(label_ColorBlockGamma) etc

Comment: Also there is a `:empty` psuedo element that can target empty html elements with css

Comment: isn't `count` out of scope in the if statement because `count` is declared within that `using` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your only issue is that you are attempting to hide a string.  Let's turn that string into a selector and use it to target a specific element using jQuery.

```js
function hideSelect(args) {
  $(`#${args}`).hide();
  console.log(args);
}

hideSelect("label_something_something");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="label_something_something">
  Can you see me?
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use Razor syntax instead of going through all of the trouble with javascript?

```
if(data.Documents.Count > 0){
    <label id='label_@data.test.Replace(".",@function_name).Replace(" ","")'><input type="checkbox" class="selectall" /> Select all</label>
}
```

or

```
<label id='label_@data.test.Replace(".",@function_name).Replace(" ","")' @if(data.Documents.Count == 0){<text>style='display:none;'</text>}><input type="checkbox" class="selectall" /> Select all</label>
```